# How does Invoke-RestMethod parse a JSON response into a PS object

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I am querying the Microsoft Graph API using Powershell and Invoke-RestMethod.
My query is:

```
$GraphAPIReturn = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accesstoken)"} -Uri $GraphAPIResource -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

When the result is returned, I can display the `GraphAPIReturn` variable, and get some data that looks like:

```
TotalRowCount : 920
Schema        : {@{Column=AppInstallState; PropertyType=String}, @{Column=AppInstallState_loc; PropertyType=String}, @{Column=AppInstallStateDetails; PropertyType=String}, @{Column=AppInstallStateDetails_loc; PropertyType=String}…}
Values        : {S1 Installed E0  39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 6.96.170 False  5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f Machine-Name   1 0 10/10/2023 10:13:30 Windows 10.0.19045.3570 82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159 Username Email, S1 Installed E0  
            39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 6.96.170 False  f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83 Machine-Name   1 0 12/10/2023 10:38:23 Windows 10.0.22621.2428 b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4 Username Email, S1 Installed E0  
            39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 6.96.170 False  1204947b-45e4-44db-8276-c4cfa73c676d Machine-Name   1 0 28/09/2023 09:07:43 Windows 10.0.22621.2428 ada75844-368f-445e-9e8c-21c57c8bae6e Username Email, S1 Installed E0  
            39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 6.96.170 False  2747782c-fdd7-4b76-b983-8e5694021a60 Machine-Name   1 0 16/09/2023 21:57:46 Windows 10.0.22621.2428 d61099b3-f4d3-4e19-bcb8-1481d098b848 username Email…}
SessionId     : 
AppName       : 'Our Intune App Name'
```

If I call `$GraphAPIReturn.Values`, I am expecting to get the `Values` property of the returned object, with the data being just what was shown for the `Values` property in the example above.

Instead, I get one of these for each returned entry:

```
Length         : 19
LongLength     : 19
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {S1, Installed, E0, …}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 19
AppName        : 'Our Intune App Name'
```

This looks odd to me, as does not seem to match what is shown in the original variable. If I try to get to the `SyncRoot` property, it gives me the same data as just showing `Values`.

What's odd, is if I do exactly the same thing I am doing in the Intune portal, and pull the JSON response from Edge developer tools, I can put this into `ConvertFrom-JSON` and it then behaves as expected. I can call the `Values` property, and it gives me the data in a format I would expect.

My question is, does Invoke-RestMethod parse the JSON differently to ConvertFrom-JSON? If so, how do I need to change my approach to working with the returned object? If not, what have I gotten wrong in my commands that causes it to parse differently?

**EDIT**: Example of the JSON returned from Intune portal in Edge developer tools below (truncated results to keep it small):

```
{"TotalRowCount":917,"Schema":[{"Column":"AppInstallState","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallState_loc","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallStateDetails","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallStateDetails_loc","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"ApplicationId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppVersion","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AssignmentFilterIdsExist","PropertyType":"SByte"},{"Column":"AssignmentFilterIdsList","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"DeviceId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"DeviceName","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"ErrorCode","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"HexErrorCode","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"InstallState","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"InstallStateDetail","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"LastModifiedDateTime","PropertyType":"DateTime"},{"Column":"Platform","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserName","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserPrincipalName","PropertyType":"String"}],"Values":[["S1","Installed","E0","","39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82","6.96.170",false,"","5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f","CPC-james-NSYIT","","",1,0,"2023-10-10T10:13:30","Windows 10.0.19045.3570","82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159","Allison, James","james.allison@ukpowernetworks.co.uk"],["S1","Installed","E0","","39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82","6.96.170",false,"","f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83","FD-2do7AN5hEMv2","","",1,0,"2023-10-12T10:38:23","Windows 10.0.22621.2428","b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4","Gowen, Michael","Michael.Gowen@ukpowernetworks.co.uk"]],"SessionId":""}
```

**EDIT 2**: Adding screenshots to show output displayed.

Invoke-RestMethod full output:
[image: Invoke-RestMethod main response output]

Invoke-RestMethod Values property output:
[image: Invoke-RestMethod Values property]

ConvertFrom-JSON full output:
[image: ConvertFrom-JSON full output]

ConvertFrom-JSON Values property output:
[image: ConvertFrom-JSON Values property output]

**EDIT 3**: URL being queried:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/reports/getDeviceInstallStatusReport
```

Request body:

```
$body = @{
    select = @(
        "DeviceName"
        "UserPrincipalName"
        "Platform"
        "AppVersion"
        "InstallState"
        "InstallStateDetail"
        "AssignmentFilterIdsExist"
        "LastModifiedDateTime"
        "DeviceId"
        "ErrorCode"
        "UserName"
        "UserId"
        "ApplicationId"
        "AssignmentFilterIdsList"
        "AppInstallState"
        "AppInstallStateDetails"
        "HexErrorCode"
    )
    skip = 0
    top = 50
    filter = "(ApplicationId eq '$ApplicationID')"
    orderBy = @(
    )
}
$body = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.9
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.9
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the json you're getting from the Intune portal? Your output looks like the properties of an array object (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-7.0#properties) rather than the items in the array being enumerated. Can you also show the result of ```$GraphAPIReturn.Values.GetType().FullName```?

Comment: Have added the JSON from Edge. `$GraphAPIReturn.Values.GetType().Fullname` seems to return nothing. I will look into that article to see if it may be relevant, but this might suggest Invoke-RestMethod is parsing the response differently/abnormally?

Edit: I changed it to do a `Write-Host` for the GetType(), and I think it is returning a `System.Object[]`

Comment: But the Json provided from Edge dev tools if converted from Json looks exactly like your response

Comment: What I find, is that when done via Invoke-RestMethod, it outputs the fields in the List format shown. When I convert from JSON and display the variable,  it automatically outputs in table format. The bigger difference then comes when I display the "Values" property; When done from Invoke-RestMethod, I get the weird list in my post, but when done from ConvertFrom-JSON, I just get a list of actual values from the property. I will update my post with pictures as an example.

Comment: You can use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead then in its `.Content` property you would have the raw Json but I believe this is exactly how the response from the Intune API looks like. I don't see something wrong.

Comment: I will certainly try that, although I'm still curious why the two methods I've tried behave differently, even though the output of GetType() for both of them are identical?

Comment: Sorry but the only difference I see from your API call and `ConvertFrom-Json` is exactly the same object the only difference is that one is displayed as List (`Invoke-RestMethod`) whereas the other is displayed as Table. This is because objects with 5 properties or more are displayed as List by default and with 4 or less as Table, in the `ConvertFrom-Json` example you have removed the `AppName` property causing the outputted object to have 4 properties instead of 5, thus displayed as a Table

Comment: Ok thanks, that explains that, but then what about the difference when I call up just the Values property?
`$GraphAPIReturn.Values` gives me something that isn't useful, but `$Parsed.Values` gives me what I want

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I think the OP is saying if they output the ```Values``` property (which is a jagged array) they see the properties of each child *array* entity (```Syncroot```, ```LongLength```, etc) rather than the items inside the child arrays. E.g. ```(’{ "Values": [ ["aaa", "bbb"], ["ccc", "ddd"] ] }’ | ConvertFrom-Json).Values``` outputs “aaa bbb ccc ddd” on my machine whereas the OP suggests the same response from ```Invoke-RestMethod``` would be output as 2 x ```LongLength: xx SyncRoot: … etc…``` on theirs. I may be wrong, but I think that’s what they’re staying anyway…

Comment: @mclayton Yes, apologies, I may not have explained that succinctly. The output when displaying the Values property of the two different methods yield different results. One is returning another array (Invoke-RestMethod) and one is returning plain text values (ConvertFrom-JSON)

Comment: @mclayton ah yes I see what you mean, due to the jagged array `,@(,@())`, but this kind weird response is very similar to the response from the LogAnalytics API, there is additional logic needed to handle this response and transform it into normal objects

Comment: @eds - can you provide the url you’re calling (anonymised where necessary with placeholders), and your output from ```$PSVersionTable``` - I can *try* to reproduce the issue here later today…

Comment: Thanks guys. I am working on the basis that the JSON returned by Invoke-RestMethod, is identical to that in the dev tools (it should be as the request was the same). Therefore I am assuming the Invoke-RestMethod is parsing the response differently to ConvertFrom-JSON. Entirely possible I'm wrong though. I'll put requested details in my question as an edit.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` uses the same API that `ConvertFrom-Json` uses: [JsonObject.ConvertFromJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.jsonobject.convertfromjson?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0), see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/d06eeb51bdd23b9d471455e1fb189969bbba15e3/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/InvokeRestMethodCommand.Common.cs#L291 Can you share an example response using `Invoke-WebRequest` instead that way we have something we can work on

Comment: Whatever it is, I don't think it's a *general* problem with ```Invoke-RestMethod``` - I just tried modifying simple [this PowerShell webserver](https://gist.github.com/19WAS85/5424431) to return your hardcoded json string and then using ```Invoke-RestMethod``` from a separate powershell session and it outputs the result as a list of bottom-level strings, not a list of the child array objects

Comment: Do you need all the data for `Invoke-WebRequest`, or just specific properties. I seem to have the same behaviour, where I can see all of the properties returned by `Invoke-WebRequest`, but if I try to just get the `.Content` or `.RawContent` properties, I just get nothing. Perhaps I am trying to call up this properties in the wrong way? I am doing `$GraphAPIReturn.Content`

Comment: `.Content` should work and return a _string_; `.RawContent` additionally includes the response header fields. To narrow down the original problem: is it just a _display_ problem, i.e. do you get the same _data_ in both cases if you drill into the arrays contained in `.Values`?

Comment: It's so odd! Still using `Invoke-WebRequest` I can output the entire `$GraphAPIReturn` variable and I get a lot of info, including the Content and RawContent properties in list form. If I then do `$GraphAPIReturn.Content` or `$GraphAPIReturn.RawContent` I get nothing, unless I do it using `Write-Host`. Content is just a string of numbers, RawContent contains the same JSON data as before. Using `Invoke-RestMethod`, I don't seem to be able to drill down into the properties any further than the first level, calling `$GraphAPIReturn.Values`

Comment: Tell a slight lie, I can drill down into the sub properties of `Values` but again output only shows if I precede it with `Write-Host`. If I do `$GraphAPIReturn.Values.Length` I get a value of 50 which is the result size for the query, rather than 19 which is what shows as the value for the Length property for each entry in `Values`. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Is `Out-Default` overwritten? Try starting a new PowerShell session with `-NoProfile`. `.Values.length` should be `2` based on your data: `.Values` contains a 2-element array, with each element containing a nested array of `19` elements.

Comment: Ok well if I do this, I get the same outout as I do with just a simple `ConvertFrom-Json` and `$Parsed.Values`; `$Values = $GraphAPIReturn.Values; Foreach($Entry in $Values) {$SyncRoot = $Entry.SyncRoot; Foreach($Column in $SyncRoot) {Write-Host $Column}}` This then gives me each column value from the Values property on it's own line. I think this came down to all the data I want being in an array, within an array, within an array?

Comment: Don't use `.SyncRoot` - this is jut a  property of a`System.Array` instance itself, which you don't need here. You can visualize the nested structure of `$Values` with `Format-Custom -InputObject $Values`. Yes, it is a nested array, with the structure described in my previous comment. `$Values[0]` contains the first nested array, `$Values[1]` the second. `foreach ($nestedArray in $Values) { ... }` enumerates the 2-element top-level array.

Comment: I think I have found this to be due to the original creators script having some of these elements within functions, and it's to do with the way there are a few cascading functions that return values. I was doing my testing in the inner most function, but if I instead do it at the outmost, I can more reliably output data in the way/format I would expect. Now I just need to determine how to deal with the actual data. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who assisted me in the comments on my questions.

I believe my issue with parsing of data and recalling variables, was due to the fact I was modifying someone else's script, that had several nested functions returning the results from `Invoke-WebRequest`.

I was tweaking the inner most function and having issues, but when working on the outer most function, I was able to successfully recall the values in a way/format I would expect to do normally, and that matched the manual `ConvertFrom-JSON` commands