# How can you combine a split JSON schema and values into single PowerShell object

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

I am working with the Microsoft Graph API, and trying to produce an app device install status report from Intune. The intent is to provide an Intune application ID, and get a list of devices with the application installed.

Using `Invoke-RestMethod`, I am able to retrieve the same data that is shown in the Intune portal, but the resulting JSON is not in what I would class as an ideal format for manipulating with Powershell (at least based on my current knowledge of working with PowerShell).

For example, the resulting object from `Invoke-RestMethod` looks like this:

```
TotalRowCount : 923
Schema        : {@{Column=AppInstallState; PropertyType=String}, @{Column=AppInstallState_loc; PropertyType=String}, @{Column=ApplicationId; PropertyType=String}, @{Column=DeviceId; PropertyType=String}…}
Values        : {S1 Installed 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f CPC-james-NSYIT  1 82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159 Allison, James james.allison@ukpowernetworks.co.uk, S1 Installed 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83
            FD-2do7AN5hEMv2  1 b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4 Gowen, Michael Michael.Gowen@ukpowernetworks.co.uk, S1 Installed 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 1204947b-45e4-44db-8276-c4cfa73c676d FD-3wqZZo23KVTG  1 ada75844-368f-445e-9e8c-21c57c8bae6e Penson, Mark
            Mark.Penson@ukpowernetworks.co.uk, S1 Installed 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 2747782c-fdd7-4b76-b983-8e5694021a60 FD-4MGi6Q4VYGMb  1 d61099b3-f4d3-4e19-bcb8-1481d098b848 Capp, Adrian Adrian.Capp@ukpowernetworks.co.uk…}
SessionId     :
```

The `Schema` property being an array of objects (I believe), means I can call a specific index, then retrieve a property by doing something like `$Object.Schema[0].Column` which would give me "AppInstallState". This can obviously be used to get various other column names, and their type (string, boolean, datetime etc).

The issue I have, is the actual list of devices and associated data is stored in the `Values` property, which appears to be an array of strings? Therefore, it seems a bit more difficult to recall specific devices. I have no ability to lookup one of the `Values` based on the devicename (e.g `$Values | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -eq ''}`

How can I take the schema referenced from the `Schema` property, combine it with the `Values` property, to give me an array of objects where the property names are the column names from the schema, and the values are the strings from the `Values` property.

Would I just have to manually iterate through all the values, and manually build a PSCustomObject?

**EDIT**: Details of `Invoke-RestMethod` commands:

```
$body = @{
    select = @(
        "DeviceName"
        "UserPrincipalName"
        "InstallState"
        "DeviceId"
        "ErrorCode"
        "UserName"
        "UserId"
        "ApplicationId"
        "AppInstallState"
    )
    skip = 0
    top = 50
    filter = "(ApplicationId eq '$ApplicationID')"
    orderBy = @(
    )
}
$body = $body | ConvertTo-Json
$GraphAPIResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/deviceManagement/reports/getDeviceInstallStatusReport"
$GraphAPIReturn = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($accesstoken)"} -Uri $GraphAPIResource -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: You forgot to post your `Invoke-RestMethod` call - we can't tell what API endpoint you're hitting :)

Comment: Apologies, I have added to my question

Comment: Is the Json response similar to the one shown in your previous answer?

Comment: The response is the same, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the data from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77473264/how-does-invoke-restmethod-parse-a-json-response-into-a-ps-object) there are two properties that define the data:

- `Schema` - contains a list of column names
- `Values` - contains a jagged array where each child item is an array of property values that run in parallel to the `Schema` column definitions

This format is presumably to reduce the amount of bytes needed to be sent when downloading a report with a large number of items in `Values` as it can contain a compact json array of values for each item rather than a json object that repeats column names in each entry.

Here's the sample data from your other question:

```
$json = @"
{"TotalRowCount":917,"Schema":[{"Column":"AppInstallState","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallState_loc","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallStateDetails","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallStateDetails_loc","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"ApplicationId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppVersion","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AssignmentFilterIdsExist","PropertyType":"SByte"},{"Column":"AssignmentFilterIdsList","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"DeviceId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"DeviceName","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"ErrorCode","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"HexErrorCode","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"InstallState","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"InstallStateDetail","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"LastModifiedDateTime","PropertyType":"DateTime"},{"Column":"Platform","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserName","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserPrincipalName","PropertyType":"String"}],"Values":[["S1","Installed","E0","","39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82","6.96.170",false,"","5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f","CPC-james-NSYIT","","",1,0,"2023-10-10T10:13:30","Windows 10.0.19045.3570","82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159","[redacted]","[redacted]"],["S1","Installed","E0","","39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82","6.96.170",false,"","f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83","FD-2do7AN5hEMv2","","",1,0,"2023-10-12T10:38:23","Windows 10.0.22621.2428","b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4","[redacted]","[redacted]"]],"SessionId":""}
"@;

$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$data | fl *

# TotalRowCount : 917
#  Schema        : {@{Column=AppInstallState; PropertyType=String}, # 
#  @{Column=AppInstallState_loc;
#                 PropertyType=String}, @{Column=AppInstallStateDetails; PropertyType=String},
#                 @{Column=AppInstallStateDetails_loc; PropertyType=String}…}
# Values        : {S1 Installed E0  39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 6.96.170 False
#                 5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f CPC-james-NSYIT   1 0 10/10/2023 10:13:30
#                 Windows 10.0.19045.3570 82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159 [redacted]
#                 [redacted], S1 Installed E0
#                 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82 6.96.170 False
#                 f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83 FD-2do7AN5hEMv2   1 0 12/10/2023 10:38:23
#                 Windows 10.0.22621.2428 b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4 [redacted]
#                 [redacted]}
# SessionId     :
```

and to convert it into a simpler representation you can do this:

```
$objects = $data.Values | foreach-object `
    -Begin   {
        $propertyNames = @($data.Schema.Column)
    } `
    -Process {
        $properties = [ordered] @{};
        for( $i = 0; $i -lt $data.Schema.Length; $i++ )
        {
            $properties[$propertyNames[$i]] = $_[$i];
        }
        new-object PSCustomObject -Property $properties
    }
```

This basically loops over each item in `Values` and pairs the items in the child array with the column name in the `Schema`, and then builds a PSCustomObject for each one:

```
$objects | fl *

AssignmentFilterIdsExist   : False
InstallState               : 1
AppInstallStateDetails     : E0
AssignmentFilterIdsList    :
LastModifiedDateTime       : 10/10/2023 10:13:30
UserId                     : 82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159
AppInstallStateDetails_loc :
UserName                   : [redacted]
AppInstallState            : S1
DeviceId                   : 5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f
Platform                   : Windows 10.0.19045.3570
AppInstallState_loc        : Installed
DeviceName                 : CPC-james-NSYIT
ErrorCode                  :
InstallStateDetail         : 0
AppVersion                 : 6.96.170
UserPrincipalName          : [redacted]
ApplicationId              : 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82
HexErrorCode               :

AssignmentFilterIdsExist   : False
InstallState               : 1
AppInstallStateDetails     : E0
AssignmentFilterIdsList    :
LastModifiedDateTime       : 12/10/2023 10:38:23
UserId                     : b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4
AppInstallStateDetails_loc :
UserName                   : [redacted]
AppInstallState            : S1
DeviceId                   : f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83
Platform                   : Windows 10.0.22621.2428
AppInstallState_loc        : Installed
DeviceName                 : FD-2do7AN5hEMv2
ErrorCode                  :
InstallStateDetail         : 0
AppVersion                 : 6.96.170
UserPrincipalName          : [redacted]
ApplicationId              : 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82
HexErrorCode               :
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I recalled I had to do something mildly similar a while back, so ended up copying some of my old code, which was fairly close to yours and mklement0's answers.

Answer (score 3):

> Would I just have to manually iterate through all the values, and manually build a PSCustomObject?

Yes (at least if you're limited to PowerShell's built-in functionality).

The following demonstrates this; it is based on the sample JSON document shown [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77473264/45375) (which matches the *for-display*-formatted data in your question that results from having parsed the JSON document into a PowerShell object graph):

```bash
# Simulation of your Invoke-RestMethdod call.
$GraphAPIReturn = 
  @'
  {"TotalRowCount":917,"Schema":[{"Column":"AppInstallState","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallState_loc","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallStateDetails","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppInstallStateDetails_loc","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"ApplicationId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AppVersion","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"AssignmentFilterIdsExist","PropertyType":"SByte"},{"Column":"AssignmentFilterIdsList","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"DeviceId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"DeviceName","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"ErrorCode","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"HexErrorCode","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"InstallState","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"InstallStateDetail","PropertyType":"Int32"},{"Column":"LastModifiedDateTime","PropertyType":"DateTime"},{"Column":"Platform","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserId","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserName","PropertyType":"String"},{"Column":"UserPrincipalName","PropertyType":"String"}],"Values":[["S1","Installed","E0","","39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82","6.96.170",false,"","5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f","CPC-james-NSYIT","","",1,0,"2023-10-10T10:13:30","Windows 10.0.19045.3570","82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159","Allison, James","james.allison@ukpowernetworks.co.uk"],["S1","Installed","E0","","39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82","6.96.170",false,"","f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83","FD-2do7AN5hEMv2","","",1,0,"2023-10-12T10:38:23","Windows 10.0.22621.2428","b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4","Gowen, Michael","Michael.Gowen@ukpowernetworks.co.uk"]],"SessionId":""}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

# Build an ordered hashtable of all property (colum names)
# that will serve as the template for creating individual
# output objects
$props = [ordered] @{}
$GraphAPIReturn.Schema | ForEach-Object { $props[$_.Column] = $null }

# Loop over the nested arrays in .Values
$GraphAPIReturn.Values |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Loop over the individual values in each
    # nested array and assign them to the corresponding property.
    $i = 0
    foreach ($val in $_) { $props[$i++] = $val }
    # Convert to a [pscustomobject] and output.
    [pscustomobject] $props
  }
```

Display output (2 implicitly `Format-List`-formatted `[pscustomobject]` instances whose property names come from the `.Schema.Column` input property values and whose property values come from the individual value arrays in `.Values`):

```
AppInstallState            : S1
AppInstallState_loc        : Installed
AppInstallStateDetails     : E0
AppInstallStateDetails_loc : 
ApplicationId              : 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82
AppVersion                 : 6.96.170
AssignmentFilterIdsExist   : False
AssignmentFilterIdsList    : 
DeviceId                   : 5010bc04-d22f-46ba-94bb-4bd3213ad13f
DeviceName                 : CPC-james-NSYIT
ErrorCode                  : 
HexErrorCode               : 
InstallState               : 1
InstallStateDetail         : 0
LastModifiedDateTime       : 10/10/2023 10:13:30 AM
Platform                   : Windows 10.0.19045.3570
UserId                     : 82633388-108c-4ea9-842e-ff9a849f5159
UserName                   : Allison, James
UserPrincipalName          : james.allison@ukpowernetworks.co.uk

AppInstallState            : S1
AppInstallState_loc        : Installed
AppInstallStateDetails     : E0
AppInstallStateDetails_loc : 
ApplicationId              : 39c23e0b-0098-4eb4-9613-232a005eee82
AppVersion                 : 6.96.170
AssignmentFilterIdsExist   : False
AssignmentFilterIdsList    : 
DeviceId                   : f8ec0b7a-044a-4098-be27-b680072a3b83
DeviceName                 : FD-2do7AN5hEMv2
ErrorCode                  : 
HexErrorCode               : 
InstallState               : 1
InstallStateDetail         : 0
LastModifiedDateTime       : 10/12/2023 10:38:23 AM
Platform                   : Windows 10.0.22621.2428
UserId                     : b7c24328-af42-408a-9f3b-dd23b7108fb4
UserName                   : Gowen, Michael
UserPrincipalName          : Michael.Gowen@ukpowernetworks.co.uk
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I recalled I had to do something mildly similar a while back, so ended up copying some of my old code, which was fairly close to yours and mclayton's answers.